# Issue at resizing TableViewCell and UIImageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, dimensions

I have a TableView with custom cells. Each cell displays a UIImageView that's 300px large (not all images have the same dimensions).
Then I use a width/height ratio to get the new height dynamically.

At this point, I resize both my UIImageView and the TableViewCell:

```
// In -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
// Resize my UIIMageView
cell.myImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, newHeight);

// In -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
return newHeight;
```

But I run into something weird, some of the images expand beyond their cell onto other cells.
Is there something I missed or done wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you solve this problem? I meet the same problem.

Comment: It's a bit complicated if you want to do this dynamically. I'm sorry but I can't remember how I fixed this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

simply `return new height` in `(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath"` like this

```
(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 90;
}
```